# Kendo UI [Grid Sorting] - Disable sorting/filter for individual columns

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo UI grid table.

How can I **disable sorting** for "`Action`" column and **disable filter** for "`Availability`" column

> **[Online Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/uMAHO)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<th data-field="availability" data-filterable="false" >Availability</th>
<th data-field="actions" data-sortable="false" >Actions</th>
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/uMAHO/2)

Also check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31682894/kendo-ui-grid-hide-column-when-initialize-from-html-table)

Comment: Hi **@Ademar**... Thanks for the perfect answer... If I want to show sorting icon by default to applicable fields, how can I do that? 
Can you please help me on this as well?

Comment: Check this [demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/uMAHO/3) You have to set default sort in your [dataSource](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-serverSorting)

Comment: **@Ademar**.. Thanks mate... perfect